# Jquery : Select a table by its class, then set class on rows

Tags: jquery

I trying to understand jquery, and can't figure a problem out.  I have a page with 2 or more tables on there, but I want to be able to identity all tables which have a certain class (they may have more than 1 class).  Once I have this table/tables, I want to update the class on the odd/even rows.

This works, but it sets the class on all tables, irrespective if they have the `tableData` class or not.

```
$(function() {
  if($("table").hasClass("tableData")) { 
    $("tr:odd").addClass("alt"); 
  }; 
});
```

This doesn't work (nor other versions which I've tried).

```
$(function() {
  if($("table").hasClass("tableData")) (function() { 
    $(this).("tr:odd").addClass("alt"); 
  }); 
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("table.tableData tr:odd").addClass("alt");
```

Comment: Ah you beat me to it ;p  Here's a jsfiddle of it in action though: http://jsfiddle.net/zvFCZ/

Comment: I've tried that, but the table has more than tableData as a class.  I thought that table.tableData would be explicit on the class, but I need to use the .hasClass I believe.

Comment: I've just seen the jsfiddle example JesseB. OK, there must be something else on my page causing the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  Worked OK.  I had to move the javascript to after the </html> tag and now OK...

Answer (score 1):

You could just do

```
$("table.tableData").find("tr:odd").addClass("alt");
```